# Github Actions dotnet publish and deploy with ftp

Tags: web-applications, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am working on Github Actions for one of my apps. My script all appears to work as expected but at the end of the run my website shows this error.

Now if I deploy via Visual Studio and then check the remote folder I see this
[image]

This works fine, app at https://development.spicetheworld.com/ is Coolio

So when I try the Deploy from Github Actions, first we have the script

[image]

When I run the script all appears good
[image]

But the app shows this error

[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts on where I am going wrong please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I updated to latest Visual Studio, rebuilt project and now it works.